# Adding a single pixel to an image using PHP

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, imagemagick, gd

I am using Codeigniter 2.1.3 and would like to add a single pixel to an image - I know GD or ImageMagick should be able to do this however I find them quite 'bloated' libraries. Does anyone know of relatively simple method with Codeigniter or even another PHP OOP library that would be easily to integrate?

Comment: are you trying to change a pixel of an existing image or create a single pixel image of a given color?

Comment: simply add a 1x1 pixel image to the existing image so the change is basically unoticeable (its some requirement from our seo team... i'm not a fan of them lol)

Comment: usually when seo people are talking about a "pixel" they are referring to downloading a single pixel image from the tracker's page so that cookies can be set and the tracking done. They should be able to provide the link to the image that should be included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php

imagesetpixel()

```
<?php

$x = 200;
$y = 200;

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

$corners[0] = array('x' => 100, 'y' =>  10);
$corners[1] = array('x' =>   0, 'y' => 190);
$corners[2] = array('x' => 200, 'y' => 190);

$red = imagecolorallocate($gd, 255, 0, 0); 

for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
  imagesetpixel($gd, round($x),round($y), $red);
  $a = rand(0, 2);
  $x = ($x + $corners[$a]['x']) / 2;
  $y = ($y + $corners[$a]['y']) / 2;
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($gd);

?>
```

Comment: wow - never heard of the imagesetpixel! Thanks will give that a bash :)